# post id or permalink auto-incrementing number and reset everyday

Tags: plugins, php, functions, permalinks

i wanna have a permalinks like this:

*.com/2019/10/02/0001

*.com/2019/10/02/0002

*.com/2019/10/02/0003

...

*.com/2019/10/02/nnnn

.

and the next they the number should be reset to 0001, and start again.

or the other thing i think it can be done is to edit the logic of the $post_id, and change it to this format: "year-month-day-number"
without any dashes of-course. and the number should increase from 0001. and the next day it start again from 0001.

what shall i do fellas?  or any plugins to do this?

Comment: What is it you are trying to build? Those URLs wouldn't be very user-friendly, nor SEO-friendly.

Comment: good question. its not a website for seo. its like a panel to indicate our formal letters with numbers. the website will be offline and fully private for other visitors.